# Any suggestions for defining the order of the array returned from Attribute.GetCustomAttributes

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

Ok... so the title defines exactly what I'm looking for.

Right now, I am using this solution for controlling the order:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class DefaultSortCriterionAttribute : Attribute
{
    private int _priority = 0;

    public int Priority
    {
        get
        {
            return _priority;
        }
    }

    private string _parameterName;

    public string ParameterName
    {
        get
        {
            return _parameterName;
        }
    }

    private SortDirection _direction;

    public SortDirection Direction
    {
        get
        {
            return _direction;
        }
    }

    public DefaultSortCriterionAttribute(string parameterName, SortDirection direction)
    {
        _parameterName = parameterName;
        _direction = direction;
    }

    public DefaultSortCriterionAttribute(int priority, string parameterName, SortDirection direction)
    {
        _priority = priority;
        _parameterName = parameterName;
        _direction = direction;
    }

}
```

Any suggestion how to make it more efficient?

Example of the usage in my generic class:

```
Type type = typeof(T);
if (Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(DefaultSortCriterionAttribute)))
{
    DefaultSortCriterionAttribute[] attribs = (DefaultSortCriterionAttribute[])Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(type, typeof(DefaultSortCriterionAttribute));

    List<SortCriterion> list = new List<SortCriterion>();

    foreach (DefaultSortCriterionAttribute attrib in attribs)
    {
        SortCriterion sc = new SortCriterion(attrib.ParameterName, attrib.Direction);
        list.Add(sc);
    }

    return this.CompareTo(other, list);
}
```

Comment: 1) I don't really see how you are using these three properties...
2) I don't see why you don't just one one property.

Comment: What is your sort criteria ? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?  A more efficient solution might involve dropping reflection, but without knowing your goals it's impossible to say.

Comment: @asawyer - just added an example of the use of the attribute in my generic class. I still need to change the code to sort the List in right order. @soandos - 1) see example. 2) one property does not qualify to my requirements.

Comment: What is the goal? What does CompareTo do?

Comment: @asawyer - adds default sort functionality if the object is used in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine a better approach. This is good.